# Apply css if in certain section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add `css` if user is in certain section, however I am not able to achieve it. The `css` is this(it animates my bars):

```
.swift       { width:70%;  -moz-animation:swift 2s ease-out;       -webkit-animation:swift 2s ease-out;       }
.java        { width:50%;  -moz-animation:java 2s ease-out;        -webkit-animation:java 2s ease-out;        }
.python      { width:60%;  -moz-animation:python 2s ease-out;      -webkit-animation:python 2s ease-out;      }
.backend   { width:30%;  -moz-animation:backend 2s ease-out;   -webkit-animation:backend 2s ease-out;   }
.html5   { width:55%;  -moz-animation:html5 2s ease-out;   -webkit-animation:html5 2s ease-out;   }
.css3   { width:55%;  -moz-animation:css3 2s ease-out;   -webkit-animation:css3 2s ease-out;   }
@-moz-keyframes swift       { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-moz-keyframes java        { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-moz-keyframes python      { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-moz-keyframes backend   { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-moz-keyframes html5   { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-moz-keyframes css3   { 0%  { width:0px;} }

@-webkit-keyframes swift       { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes java        { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes python      { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes backend   { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes html5   { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes css3   { 0%  { width:0px;} }
```

And this is the way, I detect if user is in the certain section:

```
 $(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        $('#skill-section').each(function() {
            var post = $(this);
            var position = post.position().top - $(window).scrollTop();

            if (position <= 0) {
                post.addClass('stye', ''); // I tried to add the css here, but it didn't work
            }
            }
        });        
    });
});
```

I want those blue bars to go from left to right only if user is in certain section. Because right now it does it on page load and user may not see it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `});` at the end of the script and missing an `)` for the `each()` method on the end. Also, you can't use `each` on an `id`, you should use a class instead, ids have to be unique. See the working snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
      $('.skill-section').each(function() { //added class instead of id
          var post = $(this);
          var position = post.position().top - $(window).scrollTop();

          if (position <= 0) {
            
            post.addClass('stye');
          }
        });// added the missing ")" here
      });
  });
//removed the extra "});" from here
```

```css
.swift       { width:70%;  -moz-animation:swift 2s ease-out;       -webkit-animation:swift 2s ease-out;       }
.java        { width:50%;  -moz-animation:java 2s ease-out;        -webkit-animation:java 2s ease-out;        }
.python      { width:60%;  -moz-animation:python 2s ease-out;      -webkit-animation:python 2s ease-out;      }
.backend   { width:30%;  -moz-animation:backend 2s ease-out;   -webkit-animation:backend 2s ease-out;   }
.html5   { width:55%;  -moz-animation:html5 2s ease-out;   -webkit-animation:html5 2s ease-out;   }
.css3   { width:55%;  -moz-animation:css3 2s ease-out;   -webkit-animation:css3 2s ease-out;   }
@-moz-keyframes swift       { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-moz-keyframes java        { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-moz-keyframes python      { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-moz-keyframes backend   { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-moz-keyframes html5   { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-moz-keyframes css3   { 0%  { width:0px;} }

@-webkit-keyframes swift       { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes java        { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes python      { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes backend   { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes html5   { 0%  { width:0px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes css3   { 0%  { width:0px;} }

.skill-section{
  background: #adadad;
  width: 100px;
  height: 600px;
}
.stye{
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='skill-section'></div>
<div class='skill-section'></div>
<div class='skill-section'></div>
```

Comment: p/s: If you really want to maximise cross browser compatibility, you can also add the `-o-keyframe` declarations ;) +1, it's a really good answer with a really nice proof-of-concept demo

Comment: @Terry. Thanks. Nice addition too.

Comment: Whoops, I meant `-o-keyframes`, forgot the plural 's' :)

Comment: @Terry, no problem, I for one understood what you meant.